# Single Pages loading with index.php instead of single.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, indexing

My single pages and posts are not being loaded by `single.php`, instead they are being loaded in `index.php`

I'm not able to figure out the reason for this. My is a template which I have made myself and the loop in `index.php` is almost the same in the default theme of wordpress 3. This is creating lots of troubles for me. What could be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages use `page.php`. If your single blog posts are not using `single.php`, then chances are either a plugin or your theme is screwing with the query before `template_redirect` fires. More information on template hierarchy here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with neither the single-CUSTOM-TYPE.php nor the single.php being rendered after clicking the single-post-link.... only index.php instead of the correct file...

What helped me was a simple change back to Standard Permalinks in "Settings" -> "Permalinks" and a restore back to "Name of the Post" (Beitragsname)....

...maybe this might help someone else as well...
greetz

[Wordpress use index.php instead of single.php to show post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200324/wordpress-use-index-php-instead-of-single-php-to-show-post/28754480#28754480)

Comment: It was a great help for me. Thank you!