# Wordpress use index.php instead of single.php to show post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My Wordpress websites are not using single.php to show posts on the website. Every time I open a post, it opens it in index.php.

My single.php looks like this

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <? echo the_content(); ?>
  <? endwhile; 
  endif; ?>
<? get_footer();
?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: What's your current setting of 'Front page displays' in your settings?

Comment: Front page displats recent posts

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with neither the single-CUSTOM-TYPE.php nor the single.php being rendered after clicking the single-post-link.... only index.php instead of the correct file...

What helped me was a simple change back to Standard Permalinks in "Settings" -> "Permalinks" and a restore back to "Name of the Post" (Beitragsname)....

...maybe this might help someone else as well...
greetz

Comment: It was enough just to go this settings page and save this again.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the LOOP is not correctly setup ensure that index.php, and single.php contains the LOOP.

The loop normally looks something like this, but will change to setup requirements.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

The Wordpress Codex site is pretty awesome and will answer most questions, check out http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Furthermore questions and discussions such as this one is more ideal if you post on stacks sister site Wordpress Stackexchange. I expect this question will be deleted or moved to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It is allready in code. i have added code snippet to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your loop.php or loop-single.php weather it is routing from these files or not this are the page from where it will bring the data from database